# Web page file upload is always corrupted

Tags: perl, file-upload, cgi, filehandle

I am trying to add a file upload to an existing web page.

Every time I upload I get a file that is corrupted.

I made sure to set `binmode` on the file handle. I also have my input *enctype* set to `multipart/formdata` in my form.

My code is as follows

```
$article{upload_file_name} = $cgi->param( 'upFile' );
$article{upload_file}      = $cgi->upload( 'upFile' );

if ( $article{upload_file_name} ne "" or $article{upload_file_name} ne null ) {

    open( UPLOADS, ">$uploads_dir/$article{upload_file_name}" )
            or die "Could not open $uploads_dir/$article{upload_file_name}";

    binmode UPLOADS;

    while ( <$article{upload_file}> ) {
        print UPLOADS;
    }

    close UPLOADS;
}
```

I also tried this

```
$article{upload_file} = $cgi->param( 'upFile' );

if ( $article{upload_file} ne "" or $article{upload_file} ne null ) {

    open( UPLOADS, ">$uploads_dir/$article{upload_file}" )
            or die "Could not open $uploads_dir/$article{upload_file}";
    binmode UPLOADS;

    while ( <$article{upload_file}> ) {
        print UPLOADS;
    }

    close UPLOADS;
}
```

Comment: For one thing, you need to add `use strict;` and `use warnings 'all';` to the top of your script; there's no `null` in Perl, so `$article{upload_file_name} ne null` checks if the filename is equal to the literal text "null".

Comment: Do you have a subroutine or constant with the name `null` defined somewhere? Your line `f($article{upload_file_name} ne "" or $article{upload_file_name} ne null)` should be a syntax error unless you don't `use strict`. There is no `null` in Perl. You want `undef`, but you cannot check with `ne` for `undef`. In fact, doing `if ($article{upload_file_name}) { ... }` is sufficient because as long as there is something that's not empty or `undef` the value will be true.

Comment: see [undef](http://p3rl.org/undef) and [defined](http://p3rl.org/defined).

Comment: See the second part of my comment. You just need to check if `$article{upload_file_name}` is a _truthy_ value. `0`, `undef` and the empty string `""` are false. Everything else is true in Perl.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the information about null I didn't realize it was not universal. However that is not the reason for the error, since I have a corrupted file it is clearly hitting my statement. I did make the change concerning null and will update my Q. Is there a difference between the cgi->upload and cgi->param?

Comment: @simbabque I made this change to my code, I still get a corrupted file. I am more concerned with the upload portion than my if condition, without the if statement the outcome is the same.

Comment: @gflynn94: Please don't edit your question in a way that makes nonsense of the help you already have. If you have changed your code then you should ask a new question.

Comment: @gflynn94: *"thank you for the information about null I didn't realize it was not universal"* No, it is not even common. At present I can't think of a single language that uses `null`.

Comment: This problem is because the OP doesn't understand even the basics of Perl, and would prefer to enrol the rest of the world in fixing it for him instead of putting in some work. Stack Overflow isn't here to teach a language, and so it is ***too broad***.

Comment: @gflynn94: For goodness sake, what do you imagine `print UPLOADS` does?

Comment: @borodin I clearly upset SOMEBODY. null is a common term? It is in C#, Ruby, PHP, and JavaScript for a few examples. Print UPLOADS does exactly what I thought it did I just had the glob scenario going on that  I didn't know about. The question has been answered you can move on. Thank you.

Comment: And before you go on about how PHP uses  is_null() and  how Ruby use nil, I know the point is null is a common thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<$article{upload_file}>
```

is not doing what you think it is doing. The diamond operator (`<>`) is used to stand in for Perl's [`readline`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#readline) function, but it has a second meaning where it does the same thing as Perl's [`glob`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#glob) function. And in Perl's parsing rules, `<$hash{key}>` is always treated as `glob`.

[`perldoc -f perlop`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#I/O-Operators) explains:

> If what's within the angle brackets is neither a filehandle nor a simple scalar variable containing a filehandle name, typeglob, or typeglob reference, it is interpreted as a filename pattern to be globbed, and either a list of filenames or the next filename in the list is returned, depending on context. This distinction is determined on syntactic grounds alone. That means <$x> is always a readline() from an indirect handle, but <$hash{key}> is always a glob(). That's because $x is a simple scalar variable, but $hash{key} is not--it's a hash element. Even <$x > (note the extra space) is treated as glob("$x "), not readline($x).

There are at least a couple of workarounds:

1. Use explicit `readline` call:

   ```
   while (readline($article{upload_file}))
   ```
2. Assign filehandle to a simple scalar

   ```
   my $upload_fh = $article{upload_file};
   ...
   while (<$upload_fh>)
   ```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what it was. I was starting to suspect something with the hash, as I ran in to a weird bug. `my %hash(action =>$cgi->param('action'));` was returning "Action" rather than "". However when I set my hash like this... `my %hash; $hash{action} = $cgi->param('action');` I got my expected result. Just while we're on the topic is this related to the glob scenario you pointed out?

Comment: @gflynn94: Please don't treat Stack Overflow as a forum. It is a compendium of questions and answers that is much more like *Wikipedia*. You should add words here only if you imagine that they may be useful to the rest of the world, and you should write your submissions as if they are permanent public documents.

Comment: @mob: I would go for `$article{upload_file}->readline`, since `IO::File` has been loaded on demand since Perl v5.14.

Comment: @Borodin I was asking a general question about the same topic. I think that this is acceptable since I did not know about the glob scenario. Secondly I don't think it's hurting anyone if no one answers the question. I marked the question as answered. Thank you all for the feed back.

Comment: @gflynn94: Your statement `my %hash(action =>$cgi->param('action'));` won't even compile. If you have another question then please post it as such.